# Min-cost-flow to max-flow

Tags: algorithm, reduction

Is there a reduction from the min cost flow problem to the max-flow problem? Or viceversa? I would like to use a min cost flow algorithm to solve a max-flow problem.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the successive shortest path and capacity scaling methods for solving the minimum cost flow problem are generalizations of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm for solving maximum flow problems.  Also, the cost scaling algorithm can be seen as a generalization of the push-relabel algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I think I misunderstand the question the first time. Yes, [Minimum Cost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) is a special case for max flow. Rather than max flow, min cost assumes that after going through each edge, there is a cost to the flow. Therefore, if you set the cost at each edge to be zero, then min cost is reduced to the max flow.

**Edit:**

Since min cost problem needs a pre-defined required flow to send to begin with. You will need to run the above algorithm (with cost of edge `c(u, v) = 0`) for multiple times to search for the maximum value. For a given range of values, [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) can be used to more efficiently locate the max

Do you mean [Min Cut Max Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem)?  (**Edit:** I do not think you meant this, but this is the basis of proving max flow, worth looking at if you have not)
I will be easier to understand if you drop a graph and do a min cut yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I meant the Min Cut Max Flow problem. So I guess what you mean is this: Assume a supply, and make all the costs 0. Solve the min cost flow problem. If it is feasible, then increase the supply otherwise decrease the supply and run the algorithm again. We need to do a search on the supply values like this. Am I right?

Comment: I agree, you will need a for loop of some sort. Others suggest binary search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem

Answer (score 1):

Add a cost (per unit flow) of -1 to each edge, then use your minimise cost algorithm. That will maximise the flow.

Comment: Incorrect answer: you would have to set the cost to 0 rather than -1.

Comment: Upvoting as this is the only way to cancel a downvote. Clicked by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer may be practical. Proofing that Max-Flow is a special case of Min-Cost-Flow there is another possibility. My solution takes one iteration of the minimum-mean-cycle-cancelling algorithm in `O(m^3 n^2 log n)` (cause c is not conservative):

```
1. set c(e) = 0 for all edges in G
2. add edge (t,s) with inf capacity and c((t,s)) = -1
3. start MIN-MEAN-CYCLE-CANCELLING on modified graph G'
```

**correctness**: Algorithm is searching for residual circles with negative weight. As long as there is an augmentive path from s to t there are negative weighted residual circles.